# Scope/Lifetime of a strong reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, swift

How long does a strong reference will persist in an application.
Does it become nil after losing it's scope or it will persist until app termination?
I am Unable to understand What is the lifetime of a strong reference.
Any example's much helpful.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

An object referenced with a strong pointer will exist as long as the object referencing it exists.

Look at this reference at apple, it's really important to understand these concepts!
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: how long it is present if i don't make it as nil thats what my question is.

Comment: It's present until the last strong referencing objects gets destroyed and otherwise until the application exits.